# Using the MX Master 3 mouse over bluetooth on different laptops

Tags: laptop, bluetooth, logitech-mouse

The Logitech MX Master 3 mouse has a button on the bottom to select a Bluetooth "channel" (I think):
[image]

I would like to use this mouse on two different laptops (A & B), *not at the same time*. Should I pair the mouse to each laptop using a different "channel", e.g., 1 on A and 2 on B? Or can I use the same channel? I'm asking because I rarely use laptop B, and I have the impression I need to pair the mouse again each time I use B. So I was wondering if this would be solved by using two different channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same channel but then you would have trouble if you have both laptops up and running.

I would recommend using different channels as it allows you to quickly switch between devices.